# AJAX specific HTML content not loaded

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

EDIT:

On my sistemas.html file (`section` value is "sistemas"), I have changed the div I want to bring with this ID:

```
<div class="content-sistemas" id="content">
```

And this Ajax call neither works...:

```
 $.ajax({ 
         url: section+".html", 
         dataType: 'html', 
         success: function(response) { 
            var htmldiv = $(response);
            var selectedContent = $(htmldiv).find('#content').html();
            $('.contentPanel').html(selectedContent);
         } 
      });
```

FYI: alerting variable 'htmldiv' pops up the entire html file so it gets OK the whole data, so if I call for the entire HTML file to load, it is correctly loaded on `('.contentPanel)`:

```
success: function(response) { 
    $('.contentPanel').html(response);
}
```

**The problem comes when trying to bring only `#content` div.**

---

I have this **working OK** function, bringing to my current page all content included on an HTML file (example, when `section` variable is "sistemas", it loads `sistemas.html` perfectly:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: section+".html", 
    dataType: 'html', 
    success: function(response) { 
        $('.contentPanel').html(response);
    }
});
```

But when I try to select ONLY an specific part of that HTML, it just brings nothing. The specific content on the file is inside a DIV with a class starting with "content-" and then the name stored on `section` variable (example: `content-sistemas`):

```
$.ajax({ 
     url: section+".html", 
     dataType: 'html', 
     success: function(response) { 
         $('.contentPanel').html(jQuery(response).find('.content-'+section).html());
     }
 });
```

Shouldn't this be working fine? In this last example there is a div on the HTML file that should be loaded:

```
<div class="content-sistemas">
      <div class="bkSistemas"></div>
          ...
```

Comment: What is the value of `response` on `success` and is there a console error in the browser console?

Comment: The value of response is the entire HTML content on the document under "url:" parameter. There is no error on console.

Comment: is the div you want at root level of the html returned? If so `find()` won't get it, would need filter()

Comment: Every html files are on root level

Comment: I have added an edit at the top of the post simplfying the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was solved by this way:

```
$.ajax({  url: section+".html",  
          dataType: 'html',  
          success: function(response) {   
            var div = $('#content', $(response));
            $('.contentPanel').html(div);         } 
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Break up your problem into parts. Test each part separately.

First part: Can you update the correct div? Hard code some data to stick in there. For example:

```
success: function(response) { 
    $('.content-'+section).html("This is working");
}
```

If that works, then test the data you get back -- is it what you expect?

```
success: function(response) { 
    $('.content-'+section).html(response);
}
```

Finally, start extracting the data into a variable and examining the variable:

```
success: function(response) { 
    var ttt = jQuery(response).find('.contentPanel').html();
    alert(ttt);
    $('.content-'+section).html(jQuery(response).find('.contentPanel').html());
}
```

I suspect you will find that your problem is in how you parse / isolate out the contentPanel section of your returned HTML. This technique will help you solve the problem by yourself, most quickly.

Comment: Thamk you for your usefukl answer. I am trying this.

Comment: 1- Works. ('.contentPanel') is the one which must load specific content (not the one you suggested), and it does load that piece of text

Comment: 2.- YES. ('.contentPanel') is filled with the entire html file (in this case, sistemas.html), so this works fine. Now I need it to bring only specific content.

Comment: 3 DOES NOT WORK. Here is where I have the problem. This: "var ttt = jQuery(response).find('.content-'+section).html();", when aleterd, brings nothing, and inside the file sistemas.html THERE IS a div with class "content-sistemas".

Comment: I have added an edit at the top of the post simplfying the problem

Comment: Excellent information. Now, recall that the variable `response` contains the entire HTML document, as a single string. All that remains is how to parse the string and extract the data you need. For this, you can use string tools, such as `var csLoc = response.indexOf('content-')` (to find the `class='content-` section, and other string manipulators, such as substr() etc. Turning the response var into a jQuery object may not be necessary, or it may help.

Comment: Huh... returns -1... so theorically theres no such a value on the document. I have tried with "var csLoc = response.indexOf('#content');", and on the html file I have created the div "<div class="content-sistemas" id="content">". I cant understand whats wrong in here

Comment: And if I use "var csLoc = response.substr('#content');", it brings the enitre HTML file instead of ('#content')

Comment: FYI: solved. Afer 2 days trying methods, this worked:  "var div = ('#content', $(response));    $('.contentPanel').html(div);" At lñeats... thank you very much for your attention gibberish

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. It's always great to hear what worked - I am studying your solution. Anyway, Congrats on solving this puzzle. What did this mean: `At lñeats` (in your last comment) ?

Comment: @Biomehanika By the way, if none of the posted answers were the correct solution, would you mind creating your own answer and expanding on the solution you posted in above comment? That will both close the question, and assist future readers. (Doing so will also earn at least one upvote - mine. :)  )

Answer (score 0):

Try with this I have added two variables 'htmldiv' and 'selectedContent'.

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: section+".html", 
   dataType: 'html', 
   success: function(response) { 
      var htmldiv = $(response);
      var selectedContent = $(htmldiv).find('.content-'+section).html();
      $(document).find('.contentPanel').html(selectedContent);
   } 
});
```

Comment: I have added an edit at the top of the post simplfying the problem